# Provide kerning/Tracking for text in android

Tags: android, android-textattributes

I am trying to increase the spacing in between two words in a text. For this I came across many sites but I found the below one with the exact information I require.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html

For example I want to use the below given constatnt

```
public static final TextAttribute TRACKING
```

for my text. How should I do it?

Here they have listed all the textAttributes(constants) that I can use with a text. But I don't know how to use this for my text. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this function:

**INPUT**

- LinearLayout ll :

  > the Layout which will be your "TexView" (make sure its orientation is vertical)
- String text:

  > the text
- Context mContext

  > the context

**WHAT TO DO**

> I commented the parts that you must edit

---

```
/*
*  Copyright 2011 Sherif
*/

private void populateText(LinearLayout ll, String text , Context mContext) { 
    String [] textArray = text.split(" ");
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    ll.removeAllViews();
    int maxWidth = display.getWidth() - 20;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params; // to be used over and over
    LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    int widthSoFar = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < textArray.length ; i++ ){
        LL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);
        LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TV = new TextView(mContext);
        TV.setText(textArray[i]);
        //TV.setTextSize(size);  <<<< SET TEXT SIZE
        TV.measure(0, 0);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TV.getMeasuredWidth(),
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);  // YOU CAN USE THIS
        LL.addView(TV, params);
        LL.measure(0, 0);
        widthSoFar += TV.getMeasuredWidth();// YOU MAY NEED TO ADD THE MARGINS
        if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth) {
            ll.addView(newLL);

            newLL = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LL
                    .getMeasuredWidth(), LL.getMeasuredHeight());
            newLL.addView(LL, params);
            widthSoFar = LL.getMeasuredWidth();
        } else {
            newLL.addView(LL);
        }
    }
    ll.addView(newLL);
}
```

---

**NOTE**

> I have not tested it ... I used it for more complex things and it was working

Comment: But is this the only way I can make use of.

Comment: I will see if you can use TRACKING... But are you sure TRACKING is responsible for the spacing?

Comment: yes. I have seen some images regrading kerning and tracking. And I m sure abt it